# Handling C linked lists in Rust code when calling C code

Tags: rust

I'm writing a shared object that needs to call the `getaddrinfo()` method from the C standard library. The function has the following signature:

```c
int getaddrinfo(const char *hostname, const char *servname, const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **res);
```

In Rust code, I can call it as follows:

```rust
let tmp = dlsym(
            RTLD_NEXT,
            CString::new("getaddrinfo")
                .expect("CString::new failed")
                .as_ptr(),
        );
let orig_getaddrinfo = transmute::<*mut c_void, fn(*const c_char, *const c_char, *const addrinfo, *const *const addrinfo) -> i32>(tmp);
let ret = orig_getaddrinfo(hostname, servname, hints, res);
```

Yuo can check the man page for how the result is stored in `res`. I'm a bit clueless with how to properly walk through C structs, i.e. how to follow the raw pointers. The `addrinfo` type referred to is `libc::addrtype`, which is defined as follows:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct addrinfo {
    pub ai_flags: c_int,
    pub ai_family: c_int,
    pub ai_socktype: c_int,
    pub ai_protocol: c_int,
    pub ai_addrlen: socklen_t,
    pub ai_addr: *mut sockaddr,
    pub ai_canonname: *mut c_char,
    pub ai_next: *mut addrinfo,
}
```

I'm trying to understand how I can loop over the `addrinfo` structs that are in `res` after the call? In C, I would do something like:

```c
struct addrinfo *next = *res;
while (next != NULL) {
    // do something here...
    next = next->ai_next;
}
```

How do I walk through the list in Rust?

Comment: Not sure where you got stuck, but you do it almost exactly like in C: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8d59d511acb4dbc76bb9b04d4a92ff6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are aware, but by using unsafe code and raw pointers you can just make a 1-1 copy of the C version. In your case, it would look a bit like this. For this example, unsafe is only necessary in the places where we read or write through a raw pointer.

```rust
let mut next: *const libc::addrinfo = unsafe { *res };
while !res.is_null() {
    // do something here...
    next = unsafe { (*next).ai_next };
}
```

You can learn more about how to use raw pointers at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html